# Django: CustomUser model does not have the attributes of built-in User

Tags: django, forms, customization

I have a problem with the CustomUser Model. Here is the model:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    department = models.ManyToManyField(Department)
    game = models.ManyToManyField(Game)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

In my user registration form, I want to have fields of User plus the Game and Department fields. Here's my form as of now:

```
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):         
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length = '200')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length = '200')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email')
```

I used User as my Model, so clearly it does not have the Game and Department fields as of now. At the same time, if I use CustomUser as a model in my form, I do have all the fields I need, but when I click the register button, an error: "CustomUser does not have a set_password attribute" appears.

Also, in Setting I have this:

```
CUSTOM_USER_MODEL = 'logins.CustomUser'
```

So how can I make the CustomUser Model have the attributes of User and have those fields appear in my form?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

When creating your own custom user model, it's usually best to subclass the AbstractBaseUser which includes those default fields and will generally make the process easier on you. OneToOne relationship to the default User model is more about expnding the built-in User model, which doesn't sound like what you're looking for. Read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model)

As Daniel mentioned in the comments, this means you're going to have to explicitly include the username field (and you obviously have the freedom to define it as you'd like, it just has to be unique). In the example below I set up email to be the username

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    department = models.ManyToManyField(Department)
    game = models.ManyToManyField(Game)
    # user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Now you need to include the password field in your form, and please look at the example given [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example), they do a better job explaining than I do.

Comment: Note that subclassing AbstractBaseUser means you need to define username/password fields explicitly on your model.

Comment: @yuvi It's not working for some reason :/ In admin, when I am trying to create a user now it's giving me this:
<class 'logins.models.CustomUser'> has no ForeignKey to <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>
And when I try to login to the actual website the error is this :
FieldError at /logins/
Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: department, game, id, last_login, password
Thanks!

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks, I edited that in (though what you mentioned is only relevant for the username, not the password).

Comment: @yudasinal it sounds like you changed your model without re-syncing your db (or migrating the schema).

Comment: @yuvi I still am struggling with that thing :( 
I switched mt database to MySQL and now, when I change the CustomUser model to what you guys said was right, I create a migration and get the following error: 
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1091, "Can't DROP 'user_id'; check that column/key exists")

how can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: That's an entirely different question about an error with migrating. I could help you here, but it's best you ask it as a different question on SO (or better yet, search around if someone had a similar problem before)

Comment: @yuvi I posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20954085/django-operationerror-1091
thanks!